# Magento Sales Order View not displaying order info

Tags: magento-enterprise, php-7

Posted this on [base StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942975/magento-sales-order-view-not-displaying-order-info) and got no traction, so reposting here to see if the Magento experts have some insight.

Having an issue where our template is not displaying the order details. If we switch the template to default, we can see these two blocks rendered:

URL pattern: `/sales/order/view/order_id/##`

```
frontend/base/default/template/tm/checkoutfields/sales/order/info.phtml
```

and

```
frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/view.phtml
```

If we go to our Argento theme, they are not displaying at all. Same thing happens on the checkout success page too, so I'm sure it's related.

Using the PulseStorm CommerceBug extension, I can see this block in the Layout regardless of which theme we have selected:

URL example for debug output: `/sales/order/view/order_id/XX/?showLayout=page&showLayoutFormat=text`

```
<sales_order_view>
   <reference name="sales.order.info">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>tm/checkoutfields/sales/order/info.phtml</template>
      </action>
      <block type="checkoutfields/view" name="checkoutfields" template="tm/checkoutfields/view.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</sales_order_view>
```

Started seeing this after we upgraded to EE 1.14.3, though not seeing where that would affect our template. We have since also upgraded to the latest version of the Argento theme to see if that would fix it and also updated to EE 1.14.3.1.

Checkout page: `/checkout/onepage/success/`

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
   <update handle="sales_order_view"/>
   <update handle="page_one_column"/>
   <remove name="customer_account_navigation"/>
   <remove name="left"/>
   <remove name="right"/>
   <remove name="downloadable.checkout.success"/>
   <remove name="sales.order.info.buttons"/>
   <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
      <action method="unsetChildren"/>
   </reference>
   <reference name="sales.order.info">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>tm/checkoutsuccess/sales/order/info.phtml</template>
      </action>
   </reference>
   <reference name="sales.order.view">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>tm/checkoutsuccess/sales/order/view.phtml</template>
      </action>
   </reference>
   <reference name="checkout.success">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>tm/checkoutsuccess/success.phtml</template>
      </action>
      <action method="insert">
         <blockName>sales.order.info</blockName>
         <alias>info</alias>
      </action>
      <action method="insert">
         <blockName>sales.order.view</blockName>
         <alias>sales.order.view</alias>
      </action>
      <block type="core/template" name="checkoutsuccess.additional" template="tm/checkoutsuccess/success/additional.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Have also tried copying the two info and the view files over to our argento/flat theme directories along with adding the layout info to the layout files there to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like our problem was a sales.xml file in our theme which was overriding the default one.